# How to make responsiveness for shortcodes in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using Marine Theme, I want to make responsiveness for my background image using wordpress shortcodes.

Example:

```
[highlight background-image="my_background_image.jpg" 
  background-position="center center" background-stretch="yes"]
 [/highlight]
```

If I try to make image responsive through this, the size of background-image is shrinking for mobile devices.

Is there any way to write media queries css in wordpress?

or

any alternate solution for my problem ?

Comment: What is the markup generated by this shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

This should all be done in your .css files, whether you are using shortcodes or not. Here's a few widths you can use as examples for your responsive styles:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px) { ... }

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) { ... }

@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) { ... }

@media all and (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Put these in your `style.css`